# I tried to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 so that I can get to 12.10-14.04

Tags: upgrade

The problem is that through terminal I get a "didn't download". There may be a problem with network connection, I am using WIFI?

Comment: That is a ton of upgrades through several releases that are beyond EOL. Just do a fresh install, it is faster and more reliable. The link karel gave you is somewhat old and involves updating your repo list and upgrading via apt-get. Note: upgrading via apt-get is not advised (the ubuntu developers wrote update-manager for a reason ;) ) . So while you can *try* to update this way, anticipate problems and all the links on how to do so warn you may need to manually update packages.

Answer (score 0):

That is an old release. Try making a fresh install of 14.04, you will not be able to upgrade with such an old Ubuntu version.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do?

Comment: Follow my steps to help you in my asnwer

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Here you are, download a supported version and be happy! Remember to always keep your SO updated!